# Provide two arguments, get a value from the line that has those two values

Tags: excel

I need help with this:
I want to have the value , when I provide 2 arguments : article and color. 
I researched and found MATCH, but from what I learned, it only receives one value. How can I use two values ?

Example: Article=Pants, Color=blue.

Sample data:

```
Article Color   Value
Pants   blue    100
Pants   yellow  120
Pants   red 60
Pants   pink    90
Sweater black   30
Sweater white   35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably try to utilize CONCATENATE function to merge values of both cell and look for the concatenated string.

Look at following image

[image]

K8 = `MATCH(K7;G8:G13;0)`

K9 = `INDEX(E8:E13;K8)`

Comment: Let's say I want to find the line that has pants and blue.
`=CONCATENATE(A2;B2)`

when I use `=MATCH(G1;A2:B7)` the result is #N/A

Comment: Look at picture I added to my answer.

Comment: Your method always gives me the last value for any color of pants(90, in this case.)

Comment: Have you changed value in K7?

Comment: I must have done something wrong the first time, now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This can be done through SumProduct function. Suppose you have values given by you in range A1:C7 then you can use the function as under:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=A2)*(B2:B7=B2)*(C2:C7))
```

To get the values for the two arguments you can drag down the auto fill handle or enter the first the first two values in a seperate range and use the function.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the common way to do this is to create a column that combines the two columns as in 'Article - Color' and to do the lookup or match on that column.